# How to add tRESTRequest & tRESTResponce in the Talend pallete component

Tags: talend

I am using trial version talend 6.2, but this tRESTRequest & tRESTResponce are not available in the EBS->REST component in the Palette, only tRESTClient is available.
So how to add this two tRESTRequest & tRESTResponce in the pallete?

Comment: How do you know that those two components should be there?

Answer (score 0):

You can add more components unter

```
File / Project properties / Designer / Palette settings
```

But I am not sure if those components exist in your version or if you need ESB edition of Talend.

Comment: Yes, you need to have TOS ESB to have access to those components, and to tESBProvider components.

Answer (score 0):

You should always specify the version and the product you are using because Talend is divided in multiple software solutions.

As stated in the documentation([Request](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendComponentsReferenceGuide61EN/tRESTRequest),[Response](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendComponentsReferenceGuide61EN/tRESTResponse)) :

> This component is available only to users of Talend Studio with ESB.

So first be sure you are using a compatible version.

Then if you need to manage palette's component list, enable/disable them under palette settings :

> - File
>
>   - Edit Project properties
>
>     - Designer
>
>       - Palette settings